# Matplotlib: reorder subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say that I have a figure `fig` which contains two subplots as in the example from the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html):
[image]

I can obtain the two axes (the left one being `ax1` and the right one `ax2`) by just doing:

```
ax1, ax2 = fig.axes
```

Now, is it possible to **rearrange** the **subplots**? In this example, to swap them?

Comment: To be clear, you are asking how to rearrange the subplots _after_ you have plotted them (presumably with the left on `ax1` and the right on `ax2`)? If you generated the plot like in the documentation example, why can you not just do `fig, (ax2, ax1) = subplots(1, 2)`?

Comment: Actually I pickled the plots on a different machine and I would like to change a few things, including the ordering of the subplots.

Comment: I don't understand how to use `plt.subplots()`. The docs (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) say `Create a figure with a set of subplots already made.`, which is what I would like to do, but then I see no way of passing the various subplots `ax1`, `ax2`, etc

Comment: @RickyRobinson - The subplots _are_ `ax1` and `ax2`.  `plt.subplots` creates 1) a new figure, and 2) a series of new subplots on that figure.

Comment: But it doesn't do what I am looking for, does it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, as long as you're not going to use `subplots_adjust` (and therefore `tight_layout`) *after* you reposition them (you can use it safely before).

Basically, just do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create something similar to your pickled figure......
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax1.plot(range(10), 'r^-')
ax1.set(title='Originally on the left')

ax2.plot(range(10), 'gs-')
ax2.set(title='Originally on the right')

# Now we'll swap their positions after they've been created.
pos1 = ax1.get_position()
ax1.set_position(ax2.get_position())
ax2.set_position(pos1)

plt.show()
```

[image]