# How to combine matplotlib figures into multiple subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Using `matplotib` I have several `Figure` objects being returned from different plotting functions. The figures are expensive to produce with specific formatting for each one, `[fig1, fig2, fig3, fig4]`.

I need to arrange these in different layouts. For examples a column containing fig1, fig3, fig4; a row containing all figures; a 2x2 grid of all figures, and so on.  I looked at `pyplot.subplots` but this returns an array of axes that cannot be set.

How do I combine these separate figure objects into multiple subplots?

My actual case has 20+ expensive figures that need to be arranged in several different layouts so I really cannot re-plot the figures for every layout combination.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by "axes cannot be set"? The array of axes can be used to plot in the corresponding subplot and set everthing pertaining to that particular subplot, for e.g `ax[0].plot(x,y)`

Comment: @sai The `subplots` function returns the `Figure` object and an array of pointers to the `Axes` objects in the figure. I need something to set the axes objects in the new subplot figures to be the axes objects from the individual figures.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I think I understood, so why not create the axes before any of your individual figures are drawn and then use the axes objects created earlier to plot the figures in subplots only once (sorry if I am being naive)

Comment: @sai I need to use the plots in multiple layouts and they are expensive to plot. So I only want to plot them once and then use them in multiple subplot layouts.  If I plot on each subplot's axes then I will have to replot the plots for each subplot layout. I don't want to do that.

Comment: Why not save your figs to png, and then show then in axes latter.

Comment: check this out! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458919/matplotlib-reorder-subplots

Answer (score 1):

did you mean somethink like [THIS](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_and_subplots.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=3)
gs = axs[1, 2].get_gridspec()
# remove the underlying axes
for ax in axs[1:, -1]:
   ax.remove()
axbig = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:, -1])
axbig.annotate('Big Axes \nGridSpec[1:, -1]', (0.1, 0.5),
           xycoords='axes fraction', va='center')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```